# How to find the file corresponding to a specific python module?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

When a python3 program uses a module "m", what line can I write to make it print the location of the file containing the sourcecode for "m"?

In my specific exemple, I am learning Django by reading the source of an app (django-wiki), which contains the following line:

```
urlpatterns += url(r'', include('wiki.urls'))
```

I want to modify the file containing wiki.urls (I cloned django so I assume I have the file somewhere). I thought I found it (src/wiki/urls.py), but then I realized that this file mostly contains compatibility functions, and my changes had no effect. Therefore I am trying to see where exactly python goes to find "wiki.urls". I used find and grep to look for parts of the urls which should be defined in wiki.urls (for example, "signup"), but this only returns this "compatibility" file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*edit*: succinctness and clarifying answer

### Quick answer:

In your case the line `urlpatterns += url(r'', include('wiki.urls'))`
 is adding a url path for Django to evaluate for some app 'wiki'. 
The source code for the urls.py file if anyone else looking at this question is [here](https://django-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/releases-0.2.5/_modules/wiki/urls.html?highlight=wiki.urls).

### Long answer:

In **wiki.urls.py**

```
# line 51
def get_urls(self):
   ... # gets the root urls & adds all other url patterns
   return urlpatterns

# line 249
def get_pattern(app_name="wiki", namespace="wiki", url_config_class=None):
... # warnings etc...
if url_config_class is None:
    url_config_classname = getattr(settings, 'URL_CONFIG_CLASS', None)
    if url_config_classname is None:
        url_config_class = WikiURLPatterns
    else:
        ... # more warning etc...
        url_config_class = import_string(url_config_classname)
urlpatterns = url_config_class().get_urls()

return urlpatterns, app_name, namespace
```

and in **wiki.conf.settings** we find

```
# line 273
#: Dotted name of the class used to construct urlpatterns for the wiki.
#: Default is wiki.urls.WikiURLPatterns. To customize urls or view handlers,
#: you can derive from this.
URL_CONFIG_CLASS = getattr(
    django_settings,
    'WIKI_URL_CONFIG_CLASS',
    None)
```

So, you have indeed found the correct file (src.wiki.urls.py). 
From the above segments, you can see that conf.settings defines URL_CONFIG_CLASS as `None` by default. Then, `if None` the url conf defines the class as WikiURLPatterns (line 249) and includes the urls as defined in get_urls (line 51). It would be here in get_urls (and the preceding lines) you would want to add your own code to other urls patterns, views, and apps.

However, these settings are becoming depreciated, see [here](https://django-wiki.readthedocs.io/en/master/release_notes.html?highlight=url_config_class#deprecated-removed) in the docs. So, digging around in the Git for the project you can see that they have [reimplemented](https://github.com/django-wiki/django-wiki/pull/827) this for modern Django. So, in wiki.sites.py see line 75 onwards for how urls are instantiated.

You also questioned where sign-up was? Check line 94 in wiki.sites.py

Comment: @amstagram I might check if the app is registered in settings as wiki or some alias. Check INSTALLED_APPS. Also, see my addition to the answer above.

Comment: The project structure is maybe less straightforward than usual because it's a testproject: 
`django-wiki
---->testproject
-------->testproject
-------->manage.py
---->src
-------->wiki
------------>urls.py`
The file urls.py above is indeed run by runserver (I tried adding some debbug output), and adds an entries to urlpatterns, but only if a compatibility function "get_pattern" is called. This function is actually not called by runserver, and modifying that entry does nothing. 

Which is why I'm wondering how to get the actual location where python finds "wiki.urls".

Comment: The file in your answer's edit is indeed src/wiki/urls.py (the version I cloned today has an extra depreciation warning for get_pattern). But the only time it defines urls patterns (for exemple "_accounts/sing-up") is if get_pattern is called.

Comment: @amstamgram updated the answer! Didn't even see this at first myself. Silly to assume, but easy to miss if you just glance at it. They have updated the urls to  "use the same strategy used for Django admin default site"

Comment: Solved, thank you! I should not have limited myself to files named urls.py when searching for "sign-up". Now looking again at wiki/urls.py, I see those two lines: `from wiki import sites` then `urlpatterns = [ url(r'^', sites.site.urls), ]`, which should have pointed me to wiki/sites.py.

Comment: @amstramgram if it answered the question please mark as answered ty, glad to help!